# Merging two data frames on rows in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge data frames in python on Fruit, the two tables are below.
any suggestions would be great I have tried a variety of things but I cant get it to work. The below two tables are what I currently have.

Thank you in advance.

Table 1:

```
Fruit    |    appl | orange |  kiwi
Shop     |         |        |         
 :-----------------------------------:                   
1        |    NaN  | 0.275  |   NaN
2        |     0.4 | -0.600 |   0.2
3        |    0.7  |   NaN  |   NaN
4        |    NaN  |   NaN  |   0.2
5        |    0.3  | 0.350  |   NaN
6        |    NaN  | 0.250  |   NaN
7        |    NaN  |   NaN  |   0.2
8        |    0.4  | 0.400  |   NaN
```

Table 2:

```
Fruit    |    kiwi| orange |  appl 
 :-----------------------------------:                   
   x     |    0.4 | 0.275  |   0.2
```

Final Product:

```
Fruit    |    appl | orange |  kiwi
Shop     |         |        |         
 :-----------------------------------:                   
1        |    NaN  | 0.275  |   NaN
2        |     0.4 | -0.600 |   0.2
3        |    0.7  |   NaN  |   NaN
4        |    NaN  |   NaN  |   0.2
5        |    0.3  | 0.350  |   NaN
6        |    NaN  | 0.250  |   NaN
7        |    NaN  |   NaN  |   0.2
8        |    0.4  | 0.400  |   NaN
 :-----------------------------------:                   
   x     |    0.2  | 0.275  |   0.4
```

Comment: Can you format your table better, and provide some data that is immediately readable from Python? Expected output would also be helpful.

Comment: @Georgy so far I have tried to use pandas but struggling to get the result I want.

Answer (score 1):

To append one dataframe to another with same column order use:

```
df1.reindex_axis(sorted(df1.columns), axis=1).append(df2.reindex_axis(sorted(df2.columns), axis=1))
```

Please take note that `Fruit Shop` and `Fruit` columns should be set as index of their respective dataframe.

Comment: different names in dfs Fruit and fruit shop, you did not handle that

Comment: @pyd Added that those should be set to index.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correct you could use `pd.concat`. In your case `table_final = pd.concat([table1, table2])`. If not specified the concatenation is done on column names, so the column ordering does not matter - apple will be merged with apple.